# "Load More" Repeater Fields via AJAX

Tags: php, wordpress, repeater, advanced-custom-fields

I'm taking the error acf POST http://sekilsati/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 400 (Bad Request)
acf  version 5.7

I haven't found anything that works if the code isn't working. like the new version but I don't know why.
Please don't find out how much time you can help. wordpress version 9.8

single.php

```
<?php
if (have_rows('sekil')) {
    // set the id of the element to something unique
    // this id will be needed by JS to append more content
    $total = count(get_field('sekil'));
    ?>
        <ul id="my-repeater-list-id">
            <?php 
                $number = 2; // the number of rows to show
                $count = 0; // a counter
                while (have_rows('sekil')) {
                    the_row();
                    ?>
                        <li>sdfsdfdf</li>
                    <?php 
                    $count++;
                    if ($count == $number) {
                        // we've shown the number, break out of loop
                        break;
                    }
                } // end while have rows
            ?>
        </ul>
        <!-- 
            add a link to call the JS function to show more
            you will need to format this link using
            CSS if you want it to look like a button
            this button needs to be outside the container holding the
            items in the repeater field
        -->
        <a id="my-repeater-show-more-link" href="javascript: my_repeater_show_more();"<?php 
            if ($total < $count) {
                ?> style="display: none;"<?php 
            }
            ?>>Show More</a>
        <!-- 
            The JS that will do the AJAX request
        -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var my_repeater_field_post_id = <?php echo $post->ID; ?>;
            var my_repeater_field_offset = <?php echo $number; ?>;
            var my_repeater_field_nonce = '<?php echo wp_create_nonce('my_repeater_field_nonce'); ?>';
            var my_repeater_ajax_url = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';
            var my_repeater_more = true;

            function my_repeater_show_more() {

                // make ajax request
                jQuery.post(
                    my_repeater_ajax_url, {
                        // this is the AJAX action we set up in PHP
                        'action': 'my_repeater_show_more',
                        'post_id': my_repeater_field_post_id,
                        'offset': my_repeater_field_offset,
                        'nonce': my_repeater_field_nonce
                    },
                    function (json) {
                        // add content to container
                        // this ID must match the containter 
                        // you want to append content to
                        jQuery('#my-repeater-list-id').append(json['content']);
                        // update offset
                        my_repeater_field_offset = json['offset'];
                        // see if there is more, if not then hide the more link
                        if (!json['more']) {
                            // this ID must match the id of the show more link
                            jQuery('#my-repeater-show-more-link').css('display', 'none');
                        }
                    },
                    'json'
                );
            }

        </script>
    <?php       
} // end if have_rows

?>
```

function.php

```
// add action for logged in users
add_action('wp_ajax_my_repeater_show_more', 'my_repeater_show_more');
// add action for non logged in users
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_repeater_show_more', 'my_repeater_show_more');

function my_repeater_show_more() {
    // validate the nonce
    if (!isset($_POST['nonce']) || !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['nonce'], 'my_repeater_field_nonce')) {
        exit;
    }
    // make sure we have the other values
    if (!isset($_POST['post_id']) || !isset($_POST['offset'])) {
        return;
    }
    $show = 4; // how many more to show
    $start = $_POST['offset'];
    $end = $start+$show;
    $post_id = $_POST['post_id'];
    // use an object buffer to capture the html output
    // alternately you could create a varaible like $html
    // and add the content to this string, but I find
    // object buffers make the code easier to work with
    ob_start();
    if (have_rows('sekil', $post_id)) {
        $total = count(get_field('sekil', $post_id));
        $count = 0;
        while (have_rows('sekil', $post_id)) {
            the_row();
            if ($count < $start) {
                // we have not gotten to where
                // we need to start showing
                // increment count and continue
                $count++;
                continue;
            }
            ?><li>xfgdfg</li><?php 
            $count++;
            if ($count == $end) {
                // we've shown the number, break out of loop
                break;
            }
        } // end while have rows
    } // end if have rows
    $content = ob_get_clean();
    // check to see if we've shown the last item
    $more = false;
    if ($total > $count) {
        $more = true;
    }
    // output our 3 values as a json encoded array
    echo json_encode(array('content' => $content, 'more' => $more, 'offset' => $end));
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Your code seems fine, at least on my end with wp 4.9.8 and acf 5.7.6. Are you sure you add actions in root of your `functions.php` and not in another function?

Comment: yes you only have this code

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: Well, you are missing something important here. 400 error on ajax usually happens when you fail to provide `action` property, but your post request has it and it's working fine. You can try to replace whole php function `my_repeater_show_more` with `echo 'hello';wp_die();` and check if that changes response, but I doubt that. You either didn't register that action or didn't ask for that action.

Comment: I couldn't understand the problem could be ajax post?